# How to resize images included in GitHub documentation pages?

Tags: github, restructuredtext

I have a README.rst page on GitHub but I am unable to specify the size of the linked images and really I don't want to include them in my repository.

See https://github.com/pycontribs/jira

Somethink like this was supposed to work, but GitHub seems to ignore the width parameter.

```
.. image:: http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/files/2015/12/PyCharm_400x400_Twitter_logo_white.png
    :width: 100px
```

Any solutions or workarounds?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like GitHub is [intentionally stripping images sizes](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/295). The do appear, however, to support embedding [raw HTML](https://github.com/github/markup/pull/526) ([reST docs](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through)). If that still doesn't work, I'd resize the image files.

Comment: As you can see I am linking to external images and I don't want to host them myself, especially because these images are subject to copyright and that's an open-source project. I would rather switch from RST to Markdown if needed, but I would not resize or host these images.

Comment: It looks like GitHub's Markdown flavor also doesn't support image sizing, but I can confirm embedding HTML with image sizes works.

Comment: Can you please add an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is still an Open issue Gitlab side:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/24212#note_496673044

And can be found several version of this issue on other closed gitlab issues: e.g. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/28294